# Dereferencing of classes is not working and this error keeps popping up:"std::logic_error what(): M construct null not valid"

Tags: c++, class, pointers, c++14, dereference

```
if(!vars[i].parents.empty())
            {
                //Vars is a vector with the type of a class which contains the vector parents(includes 
                //pointers to other objects of the same class). 
    
                cout<<"Parents: "<<(string)(*vars[i].parents[0]).name;
                for(int j=1;j<vars[i].parents.size()-1;++j)
                {
                    string parentName = (*vars[i].parents[j]).name;
                    cout<<">"<< parentName;
                }
                cout<<endl;
                
            }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you showed. The error is elsewhere.

Comment: `(string)(*vars[i].parents[0]).name;` -- Why are you casting to `string`?  What's the purpose of that cast?  Is `name` a pointer, and it can potentially be a null pointer?

Comment: What is `name` defined as? The error in question is common when trying to construct a `std::string` from a null `char*` pointer, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: On a side note - `(*vars[i].parents[j]).name` can (and should) be re-written as `vars[i].parents[j]->name` instead. Always prefer `->` over `*.`

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I cast it as a string because I kept getting erros, but name is just a pubilc string instance inside the class. And thanks for the advice of the -> :D

Comment: @Leo I wasn't the one asking about the cast, but it was a valid question. If you are getting errors, you should provide them, you are doing something wrong. A cast (especially a C-style cast) is telling the compiler "be quiet, I know what I'm doing", and clearly you do not in this case.